# Seaborn TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc add when using hue

Tags: python, seaborn

I am trying to get a jointplot using Seaborn. My dataframe has three columns and looks like this

```
     Sample        pT Multiplicity
0      Jet1  132.2770           31
1      Jet1  181.0730           44
2      Jet1  118.1880           32
3      Jet1  155.7290           40
4      Jet1  250.8600           25
...     ...       ...          ...
1995   Jet2  134.8610           25
1996   Jet2  192.9830           58
1997   Jet2  176.5910           33
1998   Jet2   60.8583           29
1999   Jet2  158.0140           54
```

When I try to use the following line
 `sns.jointplot(x="pT", y="Multiplicity", hue="Sample", data=df)`

I encounter the error
`TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc add`

I have tried using categorical variables, but to no avail. When I don't use the 'hue' option, I encounter no error.

The datatypes for the objects are

```
Sample           object
pT              float64
Multiplicity     object
dtype: object
```

Please help!
Thanks

Comment: change your Multiplicity dtype to int

Answer (score 5):

There is no any issue in your code. But your dtype of Multiplicity must be int64.

```py
df['Multiplicity'] = df['Multiplicity'].astype(int)
```